# How to know if a record was deleted using c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ado.net

I have the below code, in which for every serialnumber I search in tblSerials table and delete it from there, but the thing is that, the record may or may not be there, so I need to know if the record was actually deleted, so I can update another table that has the total qty of serials, with qty = qty - 1 (in case of deletion).

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
for (int i = 0; i <= aSNs.Count()-1; i++)
{
    string query = "delete from tblSerials where SerialNumber='" +aSNs[i]+ "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

So my question is, if there is any way to know if a record was either deleted or not from a table once ExecuteNonQuery() took place.

Comment: [Hooray, free SQL injection for everyone!](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This returns the number of rows affected.

So if you want to know how many records were deleted you need to

```
 int deletedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int numRowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (numRowsAffected > 0)
{
  // record deleted
}
else
{
  // record not deleted
}
```